# use of brick (raster) within doParallel parallel loop in R

Tags: r, r-raster, doparallel

I want to read in separate tif files inside a parallel loop in R.  I load the raster package and brick works outside the loop, but within the loop the attempt to use brick fails:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(raster)

cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]) 
registerDoParallel(cl)

tiffile="../ESACCI-LC-L4-LC10-Map-20m-P1Y-2016-v1.0.tif"
print("step1")
bdata=brick(tiffile)

print("step2")
result<-foreach(j=1:5,.combine=rbind) %dopar% {
bpar=brick(tiffile)
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "step1"
[1] "step2"
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "brick""
Calls: %dopar% -> <Anonymous>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foreach` command starts separate environments in which the raster package is not loaded so you need to provide the full namespace in the call to `brick` like the following...

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(raster)

cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]) 
registerDoParallel(cl)

tiffile="../ESACCI-LC-L4-LC10-Map-20m-P1Y-2016-v1.0.tif"
print("step1")
bdata=brick(tiffile)

print("step2")
result<-foreach(j=1:5,.combine=rbind) %dopar% {
    bpar=raster::brick(tiffile)
}
```